# PHP - APNs messages are delivered but not received on iOS device

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I am using following code to send push notification to ios devices. I am getting successfully delivered message in php side but not receiving push in iOS device.

I have checked with replacing .pem files nd also tested with sendbox and production both. Its not working both. Please provide me the way of debugging this issue.

```html
function iosTest($tToken)
{
 // Provide the Host Information.
//$tHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$tHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$tPort = 2195;
//echo "hi";
// Provide the Certificate and Key Data.
 
$tCert = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/N****d.pem';
// Provide the Private Key Passphrase (alternatively you can keep this secrete
// and enter the key manually on the terminal -> remove relevant line from code).
// Replace XXXXX with your Passphrase
$tPassphrase = 'harsh';
// Provide the Device Identifier (Ensure that the Identifier does not have spaces in it).

// The message that is to appear on the dialog.
$tAlert = 'Testing..';
// The Badge Number for the Application Icon (integer >=0).
$tBadge = 1;
// Audible Notification Option.
$tSound = 'default';
// The content that is returned by the LiveCode "pushNotificationReceived" message.
$tPayload = 'APNS Message Handled by LiveCode';
// Create the message content that is to be sent to the device.
$tBody['aps'] = array (
'alert' => $tAlert,
'badge' => $tBadge,
'sound' => $tSound,
);
//$tBody ['payload'] = $tPayload;
// Encode the body to JSON.
$tBody = json_encode ($tBody);
echo $tBody;
// Create the Socket Stream.
$tContext = stream_context_create ();
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);
// Remove this line if you would like to enter the Private Key Passphrase manually.
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassphrase);
// Open the Connection to the APNS Server.
$tSocket = stream_socket_client ('ssl://'.$tHost.':'.$tPort, $error, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $tContext);
// Check if we were able to open a socket.
if (!$tSocket)
exit ("APNS Connection Failed: $error $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
// Build the Binary Notification.
$tMsg = chr (0) . chr (0) . chr (32) . pack ('H*', $tToken) . pack ('n', strlen ($tBody)) . $tBody;
// Send the Notification to the Server.
$tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));
if ($tResult)
echo 'Delivered Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Could not Deliver Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Close the Connection to the Server.
fclose ($tSocket);
//send_feedback_request();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the following code as it working on my end

```
<?php
    // Put your device token here (without spaces):
    $deviceToken = '17b2f31afd5c9736ad48ffca8d1936046431c6fc1f3f3ac661bcbfbf97ca60cc';


    // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = '';

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'HireRightNew.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
      'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
      $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
      exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => 'Breaking News',
        'sound' => 'default',
        'link_url' => $url,
        'category' => 'NEWS_CATEGORY',
    );

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
      echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
      echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
?>
```